# Use premises to determine which statements are valid conclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given:

- I am hallucinating or I am having a bad dream
- I am not having bad dreams
- If I am having bad dreams, I see elephants running down the road

I came up with variables so I could construct each premise using correct notation.
I used:

- a - hallucinate
- b - have bad dreams
- c - see elephants running down the road.

I then formatted these premises into

- a V b
- ¬b
- b -> c

Finally, I have to determine if these conclusions are valid:

1. I am hallucinating

I concluded this is a valid conclusion by the following:

- ¬b
- b -> c
- ¬c

Using the modus ponens rule. However, I do not know if this correct because the stated modus ponens rule does not use the negation of b to conclude c, but rather just b to conclude c. My teacher did not discuss if you can conclude ¬c using modus ponens when given ¬b.

2. I do not see elephants running down the road.

I concluded this is a valid conclusion by:

- a V b
- ¬b
- ¬a

I used the disjunctive syllogism rule. But again, I have the same issue as I did with question 1 where the negation is used rather than just b. I do not know if I can still use the rule if I use the negation.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you did *both* the analysis, as well as the evaluation incorrectly!

Consider the first one. You say the key inference here is:

> - ¬b
> - b -> c
> - ¬c

Now, this is in fact *not* Modus Ponens, ... but something called the Fallacy of Denying the Antecedent.

Consider:

b: "It is my birth day"

c: I am happy

Sure, if it is my birthday, then I am happy, and so b -> c is true. Also, I can tell you that it is not my birthday, so ¬b is also true.  But, none of this means that I am not happy... I can still be happy for other reasons!

However, for the first argument, why do you analyse this as:

> - ¬b
> - b -> c
> - ¬c

When the key inference seems to be:

> - a V b (I am hallucinating or have bad dreams)
> - ¬b (I don't have bad dreams)
> - a (I am hallucinating)

*That* is the relevant pattern for the first argument, and in fact that one *is* valid, since this is Disjunctive Syllogism.

Now to the second argument. You say that the key inference is:

> a V b
>
> ¬b
>
> ¬a

Now, first of all, this is *not* Disjunctive Syllogism, because DS has a as the conclusion, rather than ¬a. And with that change, it is no longer valid. Consider:

a: the number I have in mind is even

b: the number I have in mind is odd

OK, so my number is either even or odd, i.e. a V b.  Now I tell you have my number is not odd (¬b) ... you are trying to concldue that it is therefore no even either?  Clearly that is not right.

OK, but again, why are you analyzing the argument this way?!  It seems that for the second argument, the key inference is what you had as the first one, i.e.:

> - ¬b
> - b -> c
> - ¬c

Well, we already saw that that one is not valid though ...

Comment: Ah! I forgot about that fallacy. Your explanation makes complete sense! You ask twice why I analyze an argument in the way I did and my only response would be I do not know where to start. Do you do these problems by using the conclusion you want to reach and essentially working backwards? Also, can you only use the rules of inference? Or is it common to use logical equivalencies to rearrange the premises so you can utilize rules of inference otherwise not possible?

Comment: @Zevias You analyze them by putting down the premises and the conclusion. So, the first argument becomes:  $$a \lor b$$ $$\neg b$$ $$b \to c$$ $$\therefore a$$. Now, this is valid, since the conclusion follow from the first two premises already. The second argument becomes $$a \lor b$$ $$\neg b$$ $$b \to c$$ $$\therefore \neg c$$.  Now, to show this is not valid is actually a good bit more tricky: trying to get the conclusion from premises 2 and 3 is the Fallacy of Denying the Antecedent ... but maybe if we add the first premise, it becomes valid after all? ...it doesn't but this is not easy

Comment: @Zevias As far as what you are allowed to use or not as far as demonstrating validity goes .... you'll have to ask your instructor. Some will say that you can only uise the rules of inference, but others are ok with you rewriting.  Of course, when you're not in class: use every tool you got!

Answer (score 1):

First one is correct, but not the second one.  Yes, you can conclude that the statement, "If I am having bad dreams, I see elephants running down the road," is true, since the premise is false.  However, you can't infer from this that the conclusion is true.  Consider that the statement, "If I am having bad dreams, I do not see elephants running down the road," is also true.

When we know that an implication is true, and the premise is *true*, then we can infer that the conclusion is true.